# Iterating a array data reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, syntax

```
   const rowData = this.state.market.map((market) => {
   console.log("details", market["info"])
      {
        return {
          marketInfo: (
            <div>
              {market && !!market["info"] ? (
                <div>
                  <p>{market["info"]["name"]}</p>
                </div>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          ),
          place: "place",
          area: "area",
          action: "action",
        };
      }
    });
```

I am iterating an array in marketInfo, but I am getting the same name whenever i m iterating, but in console log I am getting different names. Whats actually wrong with my code! can anyone help me with it!

Comment: Can you provide some more info what exactly you're getting in 'market' when you're iterating over it inside map?

Comment: market is an object, which contains info & inside info I have name

Comment: why don't you just do {market.info.name} ?

Comment: its showing an error , saying property info does not exist on type "Never". But thats not an issue. My concern is whenever I Am iterating over the market, I am getting the same name everytime, although I should get different names

Comment: Can you share the sandbox link?

Comment: sorry buddy, i dont have that!

Comment: Can you do something like this first take let info = market['info']. and then try to do {info['name']} ?

Comment: where I can write this! this all operation is I am performing under const keyword

Comment: Inside your map only initialize this variable that I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const rowData = this.state.market.map((market) => {
   console.log("details", market["info"])
       return {
          marketInfo: (
            <div>
              {market?.["info"] ? (
                <div>
                  <p>{market["info"]?.["name"] || ""}</p>
                </div>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          ),
          place: "place",
          area: "area",
          action: "action",
        };
    });
```

try this code.
I think you forgot to return an object in your map func

Comment: How it will work? What difference it's gonna make? Because he mentioned he's getting the same name printed everytime.

Comment: yes I am getting the same name everytimr from this code also!